# Is Finger millet flour boiled in water safe to consume

Tags: flour, boiling, malt

I boiled one tablespoon of Finger millet flour in one glass of water for two minutes and then added rock salt and drank it, it was ok, but is it the correct method to cook Finger millet four?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether that’s “the correct method” is entirely a matter of opinion. But yes, boiling millet flour and water for two minutes would result in a food which is safe to consume. Millet does not contain things like cyanogens which need to be property cooked to become safe, and any period of boiling will be sufficient to deal with microbes like E. coli which might have contaminated the flour.